# why would get_block return an 3010008 error (curl & nodeos)?

Tags: nodeos

I have installed EOS using this - https://eosio-nodeos.readme.io/docs/docker-quickstart

```
docker pull eosio/eos-dev
```

And start the EOSIO node:

```
docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v /tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config eosio/eos-dev  /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false"
```

I am now using the API reference here - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference

This works -

```
curl --request POST --url http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
```

Giving (after running twice) -

```
{
  "server_version": "4f4e5c22",
  "chain_id": "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
  "head_block_num": 1133,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 1132,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0000046c539765f73086b65cfb453fffb59b88130097064816e2b622cb1a7422",
  "head_block_id": "0000046d224758649572aec799adb313868a4fcbea3536c092e0645a33137545",
  "head_block_time": "2018-08-13T08:43:35.500",
  "head_block_producer": "eosio",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 619663,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 3253337,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199900,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576
}

{
  "server_version": "4f4e5c22",
  "chain_id": "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
  "head_block_num": 1854,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 1853,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0000073d66c1581cd561d92a80c90aff17f9e46adfaf45ba4f08b94a4aab5b0b",
  "head_block_id": "0000073edb76b2f92f995364f497899691c2f05171e68ef1b1bdff14a534b168",
  "head_block_time": "2018-08-13T08:49:36.000",
  "head_block_producer": "eosio",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 1274266,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 6692339,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199900,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576
}
```

When I try

```
curl --request POST --url http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_block
```

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3010008,
    "name": "block_id_type_exception",
    "what": "Invalid block ID",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

It seems the EOS single node chain is running. But this basic command fails. I understood eosio was installed automatically as an account.

What could be the cause of this error? Do I need to define an account manually for eosio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any block_id or block_num in your request. Try this:

```
curl --request POST --url http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_block --data '{"block_num_or_id":"1854"}'
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I am still reading all the docs so I was unaware of the JSON at the end being needed.

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference This is good source for all the rpc apis. check it out.

Comment: That is what I was using.

Comment: With each API, there are fields to be filled. So, if you fill all the input boxes and try out, you will see the full request for curl or 2-3 more languages.